# what is the output of mpegtsdemux element in gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm working on gstreamer.Is there any way to store the output of mpegtsdemux element in a pipeline to a file as I'm interested in seperating audio,video ts packets into different files.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate video and audio track after mpegtsdemux. I hope this exemple will help you:

```
gst-launch filesrc location="source.ts" ! mpegtsdemux name=demux ! queue max-size-buffers=400000000 ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoscale ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! matroskamux ! filesink location="your_video_file.mkv" demux. ! queue max-size-buffers=400000000 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! wavenc! filesink location="your_audio_file.wav"
```